# What to do about a sketchy question

Tags: discussion, questions

lets say someone asks the question

how can i hack a magento site?

i mean not that way, but in a more round-a-bout way

personally this is something in my opinion that should be flagged and removed

is there a way to flag and remove the question

i am specifically referring to this question

[Scraping data from Magento without privileged access or trust](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/78946/scraping-data-from-magento-without-privileged-access-or-trust)

which while might be useful, I mean maybe slightly might be useful, seems like a persons way of asking how to scrape a site without permission from the author, which sounds really bad to me

Answer (score 1):

There aren't a density of these which I've noticed (or they have been flagged & closed by other mods), so we can handle these on a case by case basis.

The question cited seems legit.

Comment: Im just so security conscious with my server, and when i see something like that... something i could answer in like 5 seconds with a simple bash script... something i think anyone with any magento admin experience could handle easily I just get overly cautious

Comment: No harm in that perspective.

Answer (score 1):

I would in general say close them with reason to broad.
Also add a link to the owasp.org website

For this specific case, still to broad. And its mostly basic knowledge of html parsing.